# Navigating to another page dynamically using href using node js and express ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am creating a sample blog website in which homepage contains blogs in order of the day it is posted.
The layout of the blog is like below :

Day 1

some paragraph text.....**Read More**

Day 2

some paragraph text.....**Read More**

Now how do route/redirect the page to particular post page using **Day as Id** and using **anchor tag** when clicking **Read More**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EJS Code:

```
...
<!--
day=[
 {
  id:1,
  ...any_other_data
 },
 {
  id:2,
  ...any_other_data
 }
]
-->
<% for (var i = 0; i < day.length; i++) { %>
    <a href="<%= 'example/'+day[i].id %>">Read More</a>
    <a href="<%= 'https:www.example.com/example/'+day[i].id %>">Read More</a>
<%}%>
...
```

I hope this should work!
In the above code the dynamic url will work for both the codes

[Dynamic Routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters) with Express.js

```
app.get('example/:id', function(req , res){
  res.render('Day' + req.params.id);
});
```